# How to limit the total returned results when using ElasticSearch with Tire (A Ruby on Rails Gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I tried to use `Post.search(keyword, :size => 10)` and `Post.search(keyword).size(10)`. but non of these will work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can specify the `size` option with the extended query DSL:

```
Post.search do
  query { string keyword }
  size 10
end
```

Or you can set the `:per_page` option

```
Post.search(keyword, :per_page => 10)
```